# What Do You Call Textured Envelope Seals?

Tags: terminology

I went to a spa the other day and purchased a gift card.  The gift card came in an small envelope that had a seal on the back.  The seal felt like it was made out of plastic and had a Chinese character on it.  The lines of the Chinese character was textured so that it extended above the rest of the seal.

The seal was not made out of wax and it was a sticker.  What do you call this kind of seal?

Comment: You mean it was embossed?

Comment: There are many companies that offer customized embosser plates, usually those that also offer stamps or stationary. Search for "personalized embosser" or similar.

Comment: Do you by chance have a picture that can go along with this? I understand  if that is not possible. I removed the website request as that those kinds of recommendations are off topic for our site. However once you get the name of what you are looking for that should make the search for what you are looking for easier.

Comment: It seems the answer is likely "embossed" for the terminology you're looking for. Would you be able to confirm that by responding or perhaps marking an answer as correct/helpful? As far as the close votes, I do believe that asking for terms such as this is on topic, which is why we have the tag.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are describing an embossed sticker.
There are a lot of [services](https://www.google.ca/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=SUXRV4KWPMuC8QeehJ7gCw&gws_rd=ssl#q=embossed+sticker) that can custom emboss stickers for you so you can get your own personal 'seals' as you referred to them, to close envelopes or put on certificates and things.

These are common for companies and individuals to use when they want to make something look fancy. [Papyrus](https://www.papyrusonline.com/) includes an embossed sticker with every card they sell to give them a more expensive feel.

[image: Papyrus Sticker on Envelope]

Comment: I would add that the foil seals can be quite firm, and possibly have that "plastic" feel.